# Passing character arguments to escalc function, metafor R package

Tags: metafor

I have to fit several meta regression models and I was trying to write a for loop in which distinct variables names were passed to  escalc function.

The task looks like this:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- get(data(dat.bcg))
some_vars<-c("tpos","tneg","cpos","cneg")
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=some_vars[1], bi=some_vars[2], ci=some_vars[3], di=some_vars[4], data=dat)
```

However this fails with an error.

How can I pass variable names to escalc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit ugly, but this should work:

```
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=eval(parse(text=some_vars[1])), 
                            bi=eval(parse(text=some_vars[2])), 
                            ci=eval(parse(text=some_vars[3])), 
                            di=eval(parse(text=some_vars[4])), data=dat)
```